# Prefill form through url

Tags: forms, url

I would like to fill the form on the following site thanks to parameters defined in the url, especially the referral ID.

I try http://tumblr.followd.co.nz/signup.php?referral_id=1234 but it is not working for some reason.

It works on the login page of the site, not the signup one. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your provided URL requires an account. Kindly provide some code that you are working on.

Comment: Are you asking for an actual way how to do it? You have two ways - use JavaScript for fetching and processing the GET request, or you can fetch data at the server-side and output your page with already prefilled data.

Comment: I don't want to have to code it, I need a straight url. http://tumblr.followd.co.nz/login.php?email=test for example works for example, I don't get why http://tumblr.followd.co.nz/signup.php?email=test doesn't.